# How to group these rows in Excel (not manually)?

Tags: excel

So there is this row called "Table/Column Name"

Basically it has a table name that starts with "VKX1234" # = any 4 digits

and every row afterwards is under the table VKX1234 UNTIL we reach another VKX####.

How can I group everything under VKX1234 but before another VKX####? And onwards?

Comment: I think a filter might be what you're looking for.  It will show unique values in the column of your table, so when you select VKX###1, it will show those rows, and then you can select VKX###2 to see the newly selected rows.  Alternately, maybe you're looking for a Pivot Table.

Comment: I feel that a pivot table is the best answer here if you need help with how to use a pivot table for your needs let us know.

Comment: no idea what a pivot table is